# shell insert a line every n lines

Tags: file, shell, awk

I have two files and I am trying to insert a line from file2 into file1 every other 4 lines starting at the beginning of file1. So for example:

file1:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

file2:

```
50
43
21
```

output I am trying to get:

```
50
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
43
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
21
line 9
line 10
```

The code I have:

```
while read line
do
    sed '0~4 s/$/$line/g' < file1.txt > file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
sed: 1: "0~4 s/$/$line/g": invalid command code ~
```

Comment: its reading from another file. In this case file1

Comment: Can you show sample data from `file1` as well?

Comment: I edited the question since my files were mixed up

Comment: Posted an answer below using awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps through both files without loading either one into an array in memory:

```
awk '(NR-1)%4==0{getline this<"file2";print this} 1' file1
```

This might be preferable if your actual `file2` is larger than what you want to hold in memory.

This breaks down as follows:

- `(NR-1)%4==0` - a condition which matches every 4th line starting at 0
- `getline this<"file2"` - gets a line from "file2" and stores it in the variable `this`
- `print this` - prints ... this.
- `1` - shorthand for "print the current line", which in this case comes from file1 (awk's normal input)

Answer (score 2):

It is easing to do this using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[i++]=$0; next} !((FNR-1) % 4){print a[j++]} 1' file2 file1

50
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
43
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
21
line 9
line 10
```

- While processing first file in input i.e. `file2`, we store each line in array with key as an incrementing number starting with `0`.
- While processing second file in input i.e. `file1`, we check if current record # is divisible by `4` using modulo arithmetic and if it is then insert a line from `file2` and increment the index counter.
- Finally using action `1`, we print lines from `file1`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 'Rfile1' -e 'Rfile1' -e 'Rfile1' -e 'Rfile1' file2
```

or just use cat and paste:

```
cat file1 | paste -d\\n file2 - - - -
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative with unix toolchain

```
$ paste file2 <(pr -4ats file1) | tr '\t' '\n'

50
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
43
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
21
line 9
line 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a goofy way to do it with `paste` and `tr`

```
paste file2 <(paste - - - - <file1) | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Assumes you don't have any actual tabs in your input files.