# Merge lines of two text files when PATTERN is found

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, tcsh

I am looking for an awk or sed solution to combine 2 files based on a matched pattern, like so: The PATTERN in this case is "cat". The number of lines in file 2 will always equal the number of pattern matches in file 1.

File 1:

```
I am a cat  
I am a dog    
I am a dog  
I am a cat  
I am a dog
```

File 2:

```
line 1  
line 2
```

Merged File:

```
I am a cat  
line 1  
I am a dog  
I am a dog  
I am a cat  
line 2  
I am a dog
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What should happen if `file1` contained `this is a catch` or `I am a cat.` or any of the dozen or so other interesting cases you haven't included in your sample input/output? [edit] your question to show how to handle the worst cases, not just the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this awk one liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}1;/cat/{print a[++i]}' file2 file1
```

test:

```
$ cat file1
I am a cat
I am a dog
I am a dog
I am a cat
I am a dog

$ cat file2
line 1
line 2

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}1;/cat/{print a[++i]}' file2 file1
I am a cat
line 1
I am a dog
I am a dog
I am a cat
line 2
I am a dog
```

Answer (score 3):

The `NR==FNR` construct is very handy, but it may be risky if the file you intend to load into memory is very very large.

Instead, awk can read from two files at once.

```
$ awk '1; /cat/{getline this<"file2";print this}' file1
I am a cat
line1
I am a dog
I am a dog
I am a cat
line2
I am a dog
```

The `1` at the start of the program prints the current line from `file1`, whatever that is. The second condition in the script checks for your magic word, then reads from `file2` and prints it. Your memory footprint remains tiny, because you aren't populating an array with the contents of one of the files.

Comment: Any particular reason you used `{getline this<"file2";print this}` rather than `{getline <"file2";print}`?

Comment: @thecomebackid ... Heh, yes. Because this line was recycled from [a similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36270120/1072112) that put the `1` at the END of the script rather than the beginning, thus a bare `getline` would have overridden the current line from `file1`. Excellent catch! I'll leave this answer as is, though, as it's perhaps easier to expand into something that parses the data if the data are stored in variables.