# awk beginner trying to understand awk "thought process"

Tags: linux, shell, awk, tcsh

Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621535/merge-lines-of-two-text-files-when-pattern-is-found).

I have two files:

file 1:

```
I am a cat  
I am a dog    
I am a dog  
I am a cat  
I am a dog
```

file 2:

```
line 1
line 2
```

Upon executing:

```
awk '/cat/{getline <"file2"; print};1' file1
line 1
line 1
I am a dog
I am a dog
line 2
line 2
I am a dog
```

I am expecting:

```
line 1
I am a cat
I am a dog
I am a dog
line 2
I am a cat
I am a dog
```

My understanding of awk in the above code:

Read line from file 1, if `cat` exists print line from `file 2` and the `1` at the end tells awk to also print the line from `file 1`. If `cat` is not found, awk prints nothing from `file 2` but still will print the corresponding line from `file 1`.

What appears to be happening is awk reads the first line of `file 1`, finds `cat` and prints the first line from `file 2`. Then awk interperets the `1` as a true to the given condition and again prints the first line from `file 2`. When awk does not find `cat` it interperates the `1` as a true and prints from `file 1`?

Something else I found interesting is when I run this:

```
awk '/cat/{getline this<"file2"; print this};1' file1  
line 1
I am a cat
I am a dog
I am a dog
line 2
I am a cat
I am a dog
```

What's going on here? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hopefully this is an academic question and you're not considering actually using any of the scripts in your question. If are then see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ed Morton. Not really using this for anything, just learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/cat/{getline <"file2"; print};1' file1
line 1
line 1
I am a dog
I am a dog
line 2
line 2
I am a dog
```

When the line `I am a cat` is processed, it matches `/cat/`. And so the action is performed. The action reads a record from `file2`, which replaces the current `$0`  `line 1`.  Then, the second rule fires, which consists of `1`. `1` is an expression which is always true, so it matches any record. It has no action and so the default action is print. Thus, the current record is printed, and you see `line 1` again.

The second occurrence of `cat` results in `line 2` being printed. The `getline` syntax retains an open stream associated with it, so that multiple evaluations of the same `getline` expression read successive lines.  `line 2` is printed twice for the same reason as above.

In the second example, you're using the `getline` syntax variant which reads into a specified variable name. Thus, it isn't replacing the current record. When the `1` rule is evaluated, the current record is still `I am a cat`, and so that is printed, rather than `line 1` or `line 2`.